# Start or Stop Apache without having to give a password?

Tags: macos, apache

[On Ubuntu you can do something like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/97819/339651):

```
sudo adduser {username} www-data
```

That doesn't work on OS X, and may not be the best approach anyway.  On OS X, how can you make Apache start or stop without having to enter a password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter `sudo visudo` to modify the file */etc/sudoers*.

Change the part:

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

and save the file.

If you don't know *vi*: after entering `sudo visudo` you have to change to *insert mode* by hitting <kbd>i</kbd>. Enter the additional line as indicated above. To leave *insert mode* hit <kbd>esc</kbd>. Then enter <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to write the modified file to disk and quit vi.

Starting and stoping Apache with `sudo apachectl start` or `sudo apachectl stop` doesn't require a password anymore.

---

`apachectl` requires root/sudo to execute it. Only the root user can execute the command without entering a password. Neither adding a user to the admin group nor to another group (e.g. _www) allows to execute `(sudo )apachectl` without password.

So, the least intrusive method is adding a user - even a standard user - in the sudoers file and restrict the account to execute /usr/sbin/apachectl only. The added user is not allowed to execute any other command as sudoer!

Comment: Is this better than adding yourself to a group that already has such permissions?  Or is there no such group on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment (but I have the rep to answer? What a backwards system), so this is really a response to klanomath's answer.

I just want to make sure people avoid corrupting their etc/sudoers file like I did (and had to restore from Time Machine backup).

**Do not** edit etc/sudoers in any other way other than running `sudo visudo` as klanomath said. You will likely corrupt your file and will not be able to run sudo.

Another tip: run `which apachectl` to determine the path to Apache. Mine was installed via Homebrew so the path is different.